# Total.js define view location

Tags: total.js

This may be a silly question but I couldn't find a way to change the default `views` location in `total.js`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this path in a `/config` file:
https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~FrameworkConfiguration~directory-views